# problem are coming

Tags: source-packages

```
$ apt-get -f install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
 heirloom-mailx : Depends: libkrb53 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8f-5) but it is not installable
 qbittorrent : Depends: libboost-system1.49.0 (>= 1.49.0-1) but it is not installable
               Depends: libtorrent-rasterbar7 (>= 0.16.18) but it is not installable
 tor-geoipdb : Depends: tor (>= 0.2.9.9-1) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc : Depends: vlc-bin (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: vlc-plugin-base (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: vlc-plugin-qt (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: vlc-plugin-video-output (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: vlc-l10n (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-skins2 (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-video-splitter (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-visualization (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
 xdman : Depends: openjdk-6-jre but it is not installable or
                  openjdk-7-jre but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

[image]

Comment: You need to edit your question as it is not clear what you are asking or after.

Answer (score 0):

Remove packages:

- google-chrome-stable
- heirloom-mailx
- qbittorrent
- tor-geoipdb

I am not sure if you can remove **xdman** or not. But if it doesn't do any serious damage then you can remove it.

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable heirloom-mailx qbittorrent tor-geoipdb
```

and then try installing vlc after update

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Then you can again install above uninstalled packages:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable heirloom-mailx qbittorrent tor-geoipdb  -y
```

give it a try if nothing works.